# Simplify selenium output in python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, exception, selenium-webdriver

I would like to have selenium output a much simpler and straight forward output for my selenium tests that I am currently having saved to an output log

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test3_AnswerTest (__main__.Test)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 98, in test3_FashionTest
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(.,'Answer')]").click()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 230, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 662, in find_element
    {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 173, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 166, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
NoSuchElementException: Message: Error Message => 'Unable to find element with xpath '//a[contains(.,'Ass')]''
 caused by Request => {"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"106","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"10.0.0.100:49044","User-Agent":"Python-urllib/2.7"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"using\": \"xpath\", \"sessionId\": \"fd4e8db0-a0c6-11e4-9624-f33660aa508e\", \"value\": \"//a[contains(.,'Ass')]\"}","url":"/element","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/","path":"/element","relative":"/element","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/element","queryKey":{},"chunks":["element"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/fd4e8db0-a0c6-11e4-9624-f33660aa508e/element"}
Screenshot: available via screen
```

Is it possible to simplify this output into something like this?

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: Error Message => 'Unable to find element with xpath '//a[contains(.,'Answer')]''
```

Current error message is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
NoSuchElementException: Message: Error Message => 'Unable to find element with xpath '//a[contains(.,'Answer')]''
 caused by Request => {"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"106","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"10.0.0.100:49044","User-Agent":"Python-urllib/2.7"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"using\": \"xpath\", \"sessionId\": \"12e538b0-a0e3-11e4-af45-ff6a851f3fb0\", \"value\": \"//a[contains(.,'Ass')]\"}","url":"/element","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/","path":"/element","relative":"/element","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/element","queryKey":{},"chunks":["element"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/12e538b0-a0e3-11e4-af45-ff6a851f3fb0/element"}
Screenshot: available via screen
```

Comment: check the python traceback module. https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was an error thrown during the tests and this is an error traceback.

What you can do is:

- set [`sys.tracebacklimit = 0`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.tracebacklimit)

> When this variable is set to an integer value, it determines the
>   maximum number of levels of traceback information printed when an
>   unhandled exception occurs. The default is 1000. When set to 0 or
>   less, all traceback information is suppressed and only the exception
>   type and value are printed.

- have your own *selenium webdriver error handler* to clear the selenium error traceback (`tracebacklimit` doesn't affect it - you need to do it manually like this)

Working example:

```
import unittest
import sys

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.remote.errorhandler import ErrorHandler


class MyHandler(ErrorHandler):
    def check_response(self, response):
        try:
            super(MyHandler, self).check_response(response)
        except NoSuchElementException as e:
            e.stacktrace = None
            # PhantomJS specific line:
            e.msg = json.loads(e.msg)['errorMessage']
            raise


class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.error_handler = MyHandler()

    def test(self):
        self.driver.get("http://google.com")
        self.driver.find_element_by_id('illegal')

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.tracebacklimit = 0
    unittest.main()
```

And here is what is on the console:

```
$ python test.py
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test (__main__.MyTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
NoSuchElementException: Message: u'Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"illegal"}' 

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 5.401s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Comment: Thank you, this was able to get rid of the traceback but I'm still getting the json response after NoSuchElementException

Comment: @programiss thanks, could you share the current output?

Comment: @programiss got it, are you using PhantomJS driver, right?

Comment: I believe so, this is what I have currently `self.driver = webdriver.Remote(
        command_executor='http://10.0.0.100:49044/wd/hub',
        desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
        self.driver.set_window_size(1400, 900)`

Comment: @programiss the part `caused by Request...` is coming from inside the `PhantomJS`.  Updated the code to leave only the errorMessage, check it out. Thanks. (you may also need to upgrade `PhantomJS` and `selenium` to the latest versions to make it work).